# Testing Ember Mixin - as Controller

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I basically have Mixin:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({}};
```

I use it like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend(EditControllerMixin, {...});
```

Everything works fine in application.

However what I want to do and not sure how to go about is to write tests something like this:

```
const ctrl = Ember.Controller.extend(MyMixin, {...}).create();
ctrl.actions.someAction();
// assert if behaving as expected
```

The problem is that currently I have trouble with injections as `needs: [...]` does not take effect, since I am creating controller dynamically, so I guess no Ember container is present, that's why. Also `this.get()` does not work. So I basically want to create dynamic controller and integrate it into Ember runtime. Hoping for some complete examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't do that. Test mixin separately to what's possible (without trying to get needs working).

To test `needs` - create Controller Unit Tests and in tests `needs` include each controller you need.

But:

- `needs` in controllers is deprecated - `Ember.inject.controller()` is new syntax.
- Creating dependencies between controllers is bad (and hard to test - as you've seen) - why not creating a service which is easily testable? Service should be also easily tested even when included in mixin :)